# Difference between the rows in the same table (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm really stuck with comparing the rows in the same table in Oracle SQL. I need to get all the changes in before/after style.

I have table like this:

```
id      date        name    action
1       01-01-2011  Alex    smth
1       05-01-2011  Alexx   smth
1       07-01-2011  Alexa   smth2
2       02-01-2012  Leo     smth3
2       05-01-2012  Leon    smth3
```

I need to get this:

```
id      date        field   before  after
1       05-01-2011  name    Alex    Alexx
1       07-01-2011  name    Alexx   Alexa
1       07-01-2011  action  smth    smth2
2       05-01-2012  name    Leo     Leon
```

I tried to inner join the table with itself. The method I've found (please find it down here) which should help me to inner join the row with the next one returns "invalid number" error.

Mb there is more simple way to do this task?
Could you please help me?

```
select t1.id from tablename t1 
inner join tablename t3 on t1.id = t3.id + 1
```

Comment: Could you explain why there is only this one row with: `field=action` in the results: `action  smth    smth2` but : `smth` and  `smth3` are missing ? I can't get the logic.

Comment: Because I need to select only the fields which were changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`lag()`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions) analytic function :

```
with t( id, "date", name, action ) as
(
 select 1, date'2011-01-01','Alex','smth' from dual union all
 select 1, date'2011-01-05','Alexx','smth' from dual union all
 select 1, date'2011-01-07','Alexa','smth2' from dual union all
 select 2, date'2012-01-02','Leo','smth3' from dual union all
 select 2, date'2012-01-05','Leon','smth3' from dual 
), t2 as
(
select t.*, 
       lag(name,1,null) over (partition by id order by id, "date") as lg_name,
       lag(action,1,null) over (partition by id order by id, "date") as lg_action
  from t
), t3 as
(
select id, "date", 'name' as field, lg_name as before, name as after
  from t2 where name != lg_name
union all
select id, "date", 'action', lg_action, action 
  from t2 where action != lg_action
)
select * from t3 order by id, "date";

ID  date        FIELD   BEFORE  AFTER
--  ---------   -----   ------  ------
1   05-JAN-11   name    Alex    Alexx
1   07-JAN-11   action  smth    smth2
1   07-JAN-11   name    Alexx   Alexa
2   05-JAN-12   name    Leo     Leon
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c2f7412fa740334d0d6035570db11e17)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much! That's the closest thing I needed because there are more fields in my table.

Answer (score 3):

I'd start by assigning each row an ordinal according to the date (per id), and then self joining each row with its following row. Once you have that, you ccan use a couple of `case` statements to produce the before and after data:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, date, name, action, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ASC) AS rn
    FROM   mytable
)
SELECT a.id,
       a.date
       CASE WHEN b.name != a.name THEN 'name' ELSE 'action' END AS field,
       CASE WHEN b.name != a.name THEN b.name ELSE b.action END AS before,
       CASE WHEN b.name != a.name THEN a.name ELSE a.action END AS after
FROM   cte b
JOIN   cte a ON b.id = a.id AND b.rn = a.rn + 1
```

Comment: This is not working if, for the same record, both the fields are changing(For given data, this query is returning only 3 records). Also missing `END` keywords for all the `case` statement.

Answer (score 3):

`LAG()` is obviously the right method to use.  However, I would unpivot first:

```
select id, date, field, prev_value as before, value as after
from (select id, date, field, value,
             lag(value) over (partition by id, field order by date) as prev_value
      from ((select id, "date", 'name' as field, name as value
             from t
            ) union all
            (select id, "date", 'action' as field, action as value
             from t
            ) 
           ) t
      ) t
where prev_value <> value;
```

In more recent versions of Oracle, this can be simplified using a lateral join:

```
select id, date, field, prev_value as before, value as after
from (select t.id, t.date, x.field, x.value,
             lag(x.value) over (partition by t.id, x.field order by date) as prev_value
      from t cross join lateral
           (select 'name' as field, name as value from dual union all
            select 'action', action from dual
           ) x
      ) t
where prev_value <> value;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is also pretty useful. Sorry, can't match as second answer :(

Answer (score 1):

As you have two fields to compare, I have done it using UNION ALL as following:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        ID,
        DATE1,
        NAME1,
        ACTION,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY ID
            ORDER BY
                DATE1 ASC
        ) AS RN
    FROM
        MYTABLE
)
-- 
 SELECT
      A.ID,
      B.DATE1,
      'name' AS FIELD,
      A.NAME1   AS BEFORE,
      B.NAME1   AS AFTER
  FROM
      CTE A
      JOIN CTE B ON B.ID = A.ID
                    AND B.RN = A.RN + 1
                        AND B.NAME1 != A.NAME1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
      A.ID,
      B.DATE1,
      'action' AS FIELD,
      A.ACTION   AS BEFORE,
      B.ACTION   AS AFTER
  FROM
      CTE A
      JOIN CTE B ON B.ID = A.ID
                    AND B.RN = A.RN + 1
                        AND B.ACTION != A.ACTION
  ORDER BY
      ID,
      DATE1
```

**Output:**

[image]

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b4d418b43b81e4bc5c3b10cc5a57b632)

Cheers!!